# Meteor subscribe function listening on server?

Tags: meteor, client-server, publish-subscribe

Is it possible for my Meteor.subscribe to be listening on the server (not the client)? When I have Meteor.subscribe in the back end, meteor says that `TypeError: Meteor.subscribe is not a function`.

I understand that the convention is for Meteor to publish from server and subscribe in client.

Comment: I think you should read again on the publish subscribe guide, which should solve your problem. https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

Comment: Can you also please add why exactly you want to do that? Maybe you wanted to ask for a totally different thing but ended up with a quesiton that obviously can't be solved (as stated by the answers below)

Comment: Hey @Jankapunkt, thank you for the information. I wanted to do that because I want to trigger my publisher callback. That's ok, I think I figured out another way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. See the [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe). Why do you need subscription on the server side whereas you can directly do whatever generate the cursor that the publication would return?

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

you can't subscribe from the server.You have to publish the necessary data from the server and subscribe necessary data from the client.That is a key point in meteor.You should have proper understanding of publish and subscribe if you going to develop a project using meteor.Otherwise, your project performance will decrease